# How to change “Character Encoding” property of Rational Team Concert

Tags: character-encoding, rtc

The Eclipse compare view shows four properties for files stored in RTC:

- Executable
- MIME Type
- Line Delimiter
- Character Encoding

I know how to change the first three of them using the Eclipse or the Visual Studio client, but how can I change the “Character Encoding”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread mentions](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/174823/how-do-you-change-character-encoding-of-a-file-under-source-control):

> To change the file's encoding on server side, you need to load the file into an Eclipse project, then right-click the file and select "`Properties`".
>   In the `Properties`, set the file encoding to "`UTF-8`".
>   Then you need to make slightly change on the file content, so you can check-in/deliver the file from Pending Changes.
>   After that if you open the repository files from the workspace or stream and check it properties, you can see the file encoding is updated.
>
> If you are using Visual Studio client, there's no direct way to modify a single file's properties. You need to [edit `magic.properties` file](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_magicproperties.html&scope=null) to change the file's encoding on client side first, then modify the file and check-in to server side.

Note, as [mentioned in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/120996/how-to-change-character-encoding-for-a-file-using-the-java-api):

> Text encoding isn't handled by source control. It's however the client is set to interpret the file.
>   For Eclipse clients, there are preferences for the encoding that users can set for each type of file. Eclipse can also set the encoding per project. So the change you're making in the GUI isn't being shared with source control.

Comment: Your two citations indicate that “Character Encoding” is not a _RTC_ property, i.e. something RTC does not care about. However, the [description of magic.properties](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_magicproperties.html&scope=null) you linked mentions how to set character encoding. Do you know how this fits together?

Comment: @Martin it fits together as it is a metadata directly part of the file itself, not an extra properties managed by the source control (here RTC) in addition of the file.

Comment: OK, running `scm set property file.encoding foo path/to/file` sets a _User Property_ with name `file.encoding` to the value `foo`, not the “Character Encoding”.

Comment: @Martin yes, `scm set property file.encoding` will "change the encoding for files **that are checked in from the CLI or Rational Team Concert Client for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE**", meaning the encoding used by the client (user side).

Comment: I think I’m going to ask a new question :)