# What is “Character Encoding” used for in Rational Team Concert?

Tags: character-encoding, rtc

I’m a bit confused about the “Character Encoding” in Rational Team Concert, while having trouble with UTF-8 encoded files that are now stored in RTC. (I never had any trouble with these files before.)

- The “Character Encoding” shows up in the Eclipse client (at least) here:

  - File Compare.
  - Jazz SCM Properties.

[image: Eclipse RTC client showing “Character Encoding” property]

- The “Character Encoding” is not displayed in the Visual Studio RTC client, at least I could not find it. (Of course, VS has its own ways to display and change encoding of files, but these are independent of RTC.)
- I saw several files that are version controlled with MIME Type `text/plain` which have different “Character Encoding”s for nearly every revision, sometimes changing from UTF-8 to Cp1252 back and forth. Usually, only a few lines in a large file are changed.
- It *seems* to me that automatic merge with the Visual Studio client regularly, but not always, gets confused with encoding and/or byte order marks and changes non 7-bit-ASCII characters. I cannot reproduce this.

I learned several things from a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31986827/1826253):

- Encoding isn’t stored on the server, it is client-only.
- `scm set property file.encoding` sets a user property (and this even can be set to random value such as `foo`). However:
- As far as I can see, `file.encoding` is completely ignored by Visual Studio, although [this doc](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_magicproperties.html&scope=null) says:

> To change the encoding for files that are checked in from the CLI or Rational Team Concert Client for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE, run scm set property [...] Example: scm set property file.encoding UTF-8 path/to/file.

tl;dr: My question is: Is this “Character Encoding” and/or “file.encoding” of any relevance, and if yes, what is it used for?

Comment: I think text encoding should not be changed in the server because it might shadow a developer's bad configured environment. This can translate to a functional local code and an error prone production application. The file encoding is usually made upon creation of the file while in an application. Every time I thought a tool had a bug, I was wrong. Check your text editing client, it may be configured to save files with Cp1252 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

[Following the FAQ](https://jazz.net/library/content/docs/source-control/faq/index.html#I_am_told_the_encoding_of_the_file), it is used by an RTC Client (Eclipse or VS) at the **checkin phase**.

If the encoding specified there differs from the one used in the file you want to check-in, there will be an error:

> Basically, there is a text file that Jazz attempted to read when checking in the project contents that it could not because the content does not adhere to the encoding rules.  The error message should provide you with the name of file that caused the problem.
>
> **Within Eclipse, you have a default encoding for text files**.
>   To see what it is, from the toolbar select `Windows > Preferences... > General > Workspace`.
>   If this is not the encoding for most of your text files, you should change it here.
>
> When working within a team you should decide upon a common encoding that you and your team will use.  That encoding should also be available on the server (for annotate to work well).  You will need to communicate with the rest of your team what the encoding is.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am not sure how this might reduce the confusion. I don’t see this error, neither with a new nor with an existing file. Maybe this is an Eclipse-only feature, and this has changed in Eclipse since the FAQ was modified last (what was in 2012).

Comment: @Martin yes, the idea remains the same (even if the settings have changed) “Character Encoding” used for client text file, forthe check-in setp in Rational Team Concert.